# Задание такое: в матрице размером 10х12 упорядочить элементы каждого столбца по возрастанию методом обмена

Tags: c, массивы

Вот мой код: есть вывод исходной матрицы и цикл сортировки. Дополните его выводом получившейся матрицы и просмотрите достоверность цикла. Если видите недочёты - пожалуйста, исправьте  меня. Заранее большое спасибо всем, кто сможет помочь.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int A[10][10];
    int j, i, N, M, dop;
    do
    {
        printf("\nVvedite kol-vo strok v massive A: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &N);
    } while (!(N <= 10) && (N >= 2));
    do
    {
        printf("\nVvedite kol-vo stolbcov v massive A: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &M);
    } while (!(M <= 10) && (M >= 2));
    printf("\n\n Ishodniy massiv: \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = -50 + rand() % 100;
            printf("%d\t", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n \n");
    }
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
            for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
                if (A[i][j] > A[i + 1][j])
                {
                    dop = A[i][j];
                    A[i][j] = A[i + 1][j];
                    A[i + 1][j] = dop;
                }
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
```